# Find an object in different arrays of object with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to know if an item is in the first or in the second arrays in this model.

```
Model:
_id: String,
array1: [{ id: Number, name: String, timestamp: String }],
array2: [{ id: Number, name: String, timestamp: String }],
array3: [{ id: Number, name: String, timestamp: String }],
array4: [{ id: Number, name: String, timestamp: String }]
```

});

I am using these queries but can anyone help me to improve it or maybe to do it in only one query?

```
Model.findOne({_id: userId , 'array1.id': item.id },function(error, res) {
    if(!res){
      Model.findOne({_id: userId , 'array2.id': item.id },function(error, res) {
        if(!res){
          //do what i need;
          }else{
            //error;
          }
        });
    }else{
      //error;
    }
  });
```

I have already used queries like :

```
Model.findOne({$and: [{_id: userId} ,{'array1.id': item.id }, {'array2.id': item.id} ]},function(error, res) {
    if(!res){
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$or` statement:

```
Model.findOne({$and: [{_id: userId} , { $or: [ {'array1.id': item.id }, {'array2.id': item.id} ] } ]},function(error, res) { if(!res){....
```

Comment: Thank you... i have mistaken each other ( and and or ).